# Double Inheritance and Abstract method

Tags: .net, inheritance, abstract-class, base-class, delphi-prism

I have a base that is inherited twice. The second subclass doesn't provide any signature for the method clone, but the third subclass does and defines the method clone as follows.

```
  TControlObject = abstract class
  ...
  public
    method Clone:TControlObject; virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TGateControl = class(TControlObject)
  ...
  public
  ...
  end;

  TAndControl = class(TGateControl)
  public
    method Clone:TControlObject; override;
  end;
```

However, compiler raises an error that TGateControl class doesn't provide implementation for clone method. Since TGateControl is inherited from TControlObject and TAndControl class is inherited from TGateControl, the method clone should automatically be overridden for the base class clone method. Am I right?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Should TMakerObject in your code be TControlObject? If not, why do you provide the class signature for TMakerObject?

Comment: Yes, made a mistake. This is what happens when you start to copy and paste all the time LOL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the `abstract` attribute on the Clone method in `TControlObject`. This means that any class that directly derives from `TControlObject` must provide an implementation of the Clone method (see [MSDN abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)). As a result TGateControl must provide an implementation  of Clone. If `TControlObject` had a concrete implementation  of Clone then, yes, it would not need to be overridden.

So some options are to:

1. Either remove the `abstract` attribute on clone.
2. Add an implementation of `Clone` in either `TControlObject` or `TGateControl`.

And to clarify, these methods are never "automatically overridden". The derived class is able to call the base class' implementation but it would be incorrect to say that the derived class has "automatically overridden" the base class' implementation.